# Tire Gem Returns 'Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have mapped an associated field as a multi-field. I have set the 'name' property to be analyzed using a snow ball analyzer and 'exact' as not analyzed. I am able to search on this field and filter as well. I am not able to sort on this field. When trying to sort, elastic returns an error "Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field".

I have attempted creating an additional field called 'raw' similar to exact, and this did not work either. Below is my mapping and how I am attempting to perform the sort via the tire gem:

```
    mapping do
    indexes :sectors, :type => 'object',
      :properties => { :name => { :type => 'multi_field',
                                  :fields => {
                                    :name =>  { :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'snowball' },
                                    :exact => { :type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed' , :include_in_all => false }
                                  }
                                  }
                       }
end

def to_indexed_json
    to_json( :include => {
               ...
               :sectors => { :only => ["name"] },
               ...
    })
end

def self.search(params)
  tire.search(:load => true, :page=>params[:page], :per_page => 12) do

    if params[:query].present?
      query { string params[:query], :default_operator => "OR" }
    else
      query { all }
    end

    filter :term, "sectors.name.exact" => params[:sector] if params[:sector].present?
    sort { by 'sectors.name.exact','asc' } if !params[:sort][:sector].blank?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically two reasons why you're getting that error:

- You have more than one value per field: your field is analyzed and the tokenizer produces multiple tokens out of its content, which is not the case with your `name.exact` field since it's `not_analyzed` in your mapping
- You have more than one value per document: you're adding multiple values to the `name` field, for example providing an array of values while indexing.

I would check what your documents look like. In order to do it quickly you can make a [Terms Facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html) based on a script which returns the number of items included in the `name.exact` field like the following. If you get back at least one of the facet entries with term greather than 1, it means that you've added multiple values to the field at least once, thus you cannot sort on it.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "facets" : {
        "my_facet" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script_field" : "doc['name.exact'].values.length"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran the following: curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/myprj/prj/_search?load=true&pretty=true" -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"facets":{"sorters":{"terms":{"script_field":"doc[\u0027sectors.name.exact\u0027].values.length"}}}}'

Comment: Sounds like you have 1 document with 3 terms and 1 with 2 terms. Thanks javanna for the script tip! Very interesting!

Comment: @MachoGeek I meant a value greather than 1. 399 of your documents have 1 value for that field, one has 2 values, one has 3, 13 documents have no value at all. In order to sort on it you need to have 0 or 1 value.

Comment: @javanna, sounds good, I will keep digging. I think I have a little better idea of what to look for now.

Comment: Glad to know! You might want to accept one of our answers then.

Comment: Sorting works, but it omits 9 matches from the results. I gather this is an issue with how the data is being indexed.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it should work.
Just wondering if your mapping is applied.
Can you check it with a curl command?

Something like:

$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping'

Comment: Yes it returns: "sectors":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"multi_field","fields":{"name":{"type":"string","analyzer":"snowball"},"exact":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","include_in_all":false},"raw":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed","store":"yes","include_in_all":false}}}}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I updated my elasticsearch and it resolved the problem.

```
brew update
brew upgrade elasticsearch
```

and per instructions:

To reload elasticsearch after an upgrade:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
```